# Can I import from multiple packages all at once in Scala?

Tags: scala, import

At the beginning of my Scala files in a particular project, I often have lines like these:

```
package com.mycompany
package subproject

import common._
import uiutils._
import databinding._
import modeling._
```

Is there a way to create an object `ProjectImports` (or package object) that “preimports” all of these imports such that I can then simply write

```
import ProjectImports._
```

instead of the whole list, in each of my other project files?

Is this related to the way the `scala` package is imported in `Predef` with `` scala.`package` ``?

Comment: I would like to add for consideration that listing individial package imports can serve the purpose of documenting the dependencies of source files while an `import ProjectImports._` hides individual dependencies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it easily if all imports you needed are members of some traits. If you have several traits with functions, inner classes etc. you can create object inherited from all of them. So all their stuff can be imported with simple `import MyObject._`. Importing class in this way became a bit tricky - you have to create a type member for each class.

For more examples of this technique see Casbah [Imports object](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-core/src/main/scala/Implicits.scala) and [Scalaz object](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Scalaz.scala) in scalaz project.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a good trick to use when developing your own lib. You could even mix in all traits in the package object (then we would need only `import scalaz._` and no more the second `import Scalaz._`. But what about other libs that don't follow this pattern?

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted until we find out more on this issue; for now it looks like what I wanted to do in my question cannot be done as is.