# Is it possible to automatically import other packages in the caller's namespace?

Tags: scala, import

If a user imports:

```
com.my.package
```

Is it possible for me to do something in my package, so that another package gets imported as well? For example, I'd like to have `java.io` be automatically imported.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5744768/390581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. However, you can create a `package object` and put `type` definitions in it, so that you'll get aliases for classes you think are relevant.