# Is it a good style having a trait and an equally named object extending that trait?

Tags: scala

While I was browsing [Paul Phillips GitHub repositories](https://github.com/paulp) I noticed that he often uses a certain structur:

```
trait A {
 // ...
}
object A extends A
```

For example here: [scala-improving, strings](https://github.com/paulp/scala-improving/blob/master/src/main/scala/Strings.scala)
First, comming from Java, I wasn´t aware of having the same name for a trait and an object in the same scope.
And now I am asking what is it good for? What are the advantages over directly defining the object with all the trait members? Ok, I know that the trait can be mixed in, but I assume using only the object in practice.

Comment: If you have only trait you can't write `String.onil` since String is a type and you need a value to call method on. On the other hand, object is a value, so you can use `Obj.method` notation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At least one case where this pattern comes in handy is when you're building a library of functions. You can regroup the functions (actually methods, but let's call them functions in this context) into several traits (which can then be seen as modules), say, `MyLibA`, `MyLibB`, `MyLibC`, etc. Then, if for each of them, you define an object implementing it, users of your lib can easily use it by writing, for instance, this:

```
import mypackage.MyLibA._
```

(assuming `mypackage` is the containing package). Moreover, you can easily provide a way to import **all** functions of your lib by providing an object `MyLib` as follows:

```
object MyLib extends MyLibA with MyLibB with MyLibC
```

and then users can simply import `mypackage.MyLib._` instead of writing an import for each module separately. Better yet, you could define a `package object mypackage extends MyLibA with MyLibB with MyLibC`, and then users would simply write `import mypackage._`. And, the bonus is that picky users who would like to import only `MyLibA` and `MyLibB` in one line are also free to define their own “import object,” possibly even completing it with their own utility functions, or overriding your own:

```
object UserLibImport extends MyLibA with MyLibB {
    def userAdditionalFunction = /* ... */
    override def someRedefinedLibAFunction = /* ... */
}
```

… and then import all of it with `import UserLibImport._`

So, I'd say, in this case, not only is it good style, it's highly recommended to provide your functions in this way, as it allows for maximal flexibility.

(This was also briefly explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744768/can-i-import-from-multiple-packages-all-at-once-in-scala/5745305#5745305).)

Comment: This is *exactly* how I compose this kind of thing

Comment: It's worth mentioning that packages inside `mypackage` will get `import mypackage._` for free.

Comment: @pedrofurla Not always, [it depends how they are declared](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/chained_package_clauses_in_scala.html).

Comment: Philippe, yeah. But still, it's nice and nice to know

Answer (score 3):

An `object` is an obvious choice when you want a global singleton for utility methods.  Unlike Java's statics, you can pass this object around typed as an instance of the trait.

One big advantage here is that you can then create another instance of that trait/interface for use in unit tests.  Very handy if you're into TDD/BDD, statics have often been a pain in the neck when it comes to testability.

Answer (score 0):

Trait is reusable. Trait just defines the contract of object A, and may be some implementation. But this trait can be used for Mock objects and as discussed above for aggregating functionality.