# import into Spark - how to use java import statement to import multiple classes?

Tags: java, scala, import, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to import all of java.io.* into spark-shell and it is not finding the member.  How do I import packages?  do I need to import each class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Scala. So use `import java.io._` instead of `import java.io.*`.

`import java.io.*` tries to import `*` (which is valid identifier in Scala) from `java.io` and since it is not present, fails.

Comment: Thanks!  this was answered here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744768/can-i-import-from-multiple-packages-all-at-once-in-scala